# Recommendation for a C++ signals/actor framework

Tags: c++, multithreading, actor, signals-slots

I have the following requirements:

- A signal emitted from one thread can be landed on a slot from another thread. (cross-threaded) *In case of actor model: a passed message from one actor (running on a separate thread, of course) can be received by another actor (pretty obvious I know).*
- A signal can pass user defined data with it.
- Speed (should be very fast).
- Lightweight.
- Portable (target iOS).
- Easy to integrate into a project (preferably a single header file).
- Easy to use.

Basically, that's all. As you can see, the actor framework will fit as well (message passing instead of emitting a signal).

P.S. Why two minuses, People? :) Ohhhh very friendly, now it's 8 - that's better! :)

Comment: Being lightweight does not mean having a single header file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost.Signals2 is at least most of what you want: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/signals2.html

Comment: From this post https://testbit.eu/cpp11-signal-system-performance/ the speed of Boost.Signals2 is not so good.

Comment: @mikeg: 92 nanoseconds is a problem for you?  What is your required speed then?

Comment: Actually I can live with that. :) But if there is something that runs faster then why not? I mean... at least I tried. :)

Comment: Why not?  Because the faster one will come with some other downside, like reduced functionality, generality, or bugs.  Boost is well-tested and well-used (for the most part, including this).  If there's a silver bullet that would make Boost.Signals2 faster, I'm sure they'll  accept patches.  :)

Comment: I agree with you. It's about the compromise and not a silver bullet. But reduced functionality (if it doesn't used) and less generic aproach at the cost of increased speed for someone could be a reasonable compromise. That was my point.